# Laravel 5.6: Count the quantity of id_jadwal

Tags: php, laravel

I have a filtration query looks like this.

```
function DaftarMatakuliahKontrak() {
    $tahun_akademik = \DB::table('tahun_akademik') - > where('status', 'y') - > first();

    $kelas = \DB::table('khs') - > where('kode_tahun_akademik', $tahun_akademik - > kode_tahun_akademik) - > groupBy('id_jadwal', 'kode_mk') - > select('id_jadwal', 'kode_mk') - > get(); //Get id_jadwal

    foreach($kelas as $row) {
        $hitung = \DB::table('khs') - > where('id_jadwal', $row - > id_jadwal) - > select('id_jadwal') - > count(); //Count id_jadwal


    }

    dd($hitung);

}
```

Now I want the query to have the following output

```
id_jadwal           quantity
-------------------------------
100                      6
-------------------------------
150                      3
-------------------------------
```

My Model

```
class kelas extends Model
{
    protected $table="khs";

    protected $fillable=['kode_mk','id_jadwal','nidn'];
}
```

however, only 1 data is displayed which has the largest quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use group by, it groups all the results by a given column. You will also have to do a specific select, this will aggregate the data on the given rows, with all rows with the same `id_jadwal`, where you then can count, sum etc. Did map all ids to an variable, to utilise whereIn, to mimic the way you did the foreach loop.

```
$jadwals = array_map(function($row) { return $row->id; }, $kelas);

$hitung = \DB::table('khs')
    ->whereIn('id_jadwal', $jadwals)
    ->groupBy('id_jadwal')
    ->select('id_jadwal', DB::raw('COUNT(id_jadwal) as quantity'));
```

This should produce the results you suggested, if you have any questions or alignments please write, it was quite hard to grasp due to the foreign language naming.

```
id_jadwal           quantity
-------------------------------
100                      6
-------------------------------
150                      3
-------------------------------
```